# Is it possible to let Firebase generate a random key when using `dbRef.update()` method?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

With Firebase Realtime Database, I am updating several fields at once, including creating a new node, like the following example shows:

```
const updates = {
    [`players/${data.playerId}/budget`]:
      database.ServerValue.increment(-1 * actionS.val().cost),
    [`players/${data.playerId}/actions/${data.actionId}/position`]: "discard",
    // We can not use the action id as it might be used several times,
    // we generate a random id
    [`solutions/${data.projectId}/investments/${uuid()}`]:
      actionS.val(),
  };
  await gameRef.update(updates);
```

It turned out that while Firebase orders its own keys by default, it messes up my ordering. Is there a way to get Firebase generated keys when using `dbRef.update()` to change several fields?

Comment: Why are you not using pushed IDs?

Comment: The `gameRef.update` approach allows me to change several items simultaneously, almost like a transaction, just faster. I wanted to avoid a separate push call to minimize the risk of failure.